# warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-warnings

I have this code and there is something I do not understand

When I compile the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {

double x=1;
double y=0;

  if (x!=y)
  {
    printf("x!=y\n");
  }
  if (x=y)
  {
  printf("x=y\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I get get the following warning: *warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value*

When I run the programm I get the following output

```
x!=y
x=y
```

Why is it printing x=y if if '=' is not to compare but just to put the value there is in y in x.

Comment: I know. still it does not answer my question

Comment: It doesn't print `x=y` for me. http://ideone.com/bsmVgy

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't see that you seem to get the `"x=y"` output too. That can only happen with a totally borked compiler, since `y` is 0. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: -1 for something that's not reproducible.

Comment: My guess is that the program you ran (that *did* output `x=y`) is not exactly the program you posted. Did a source change not get recompiled ?  Or in some other way did the wrong binary get run?

Comment: Could not reproduce on both MSVC and GCC.

Answer (score 8):

The compiler is warning you that the result of the expression `x = y` is used inside a conditional; I mention this even though it does not appear to be related to your actual question because *these days, usually* it means that there's a typo and the author meant to write `==` instead.

Regarding the question: since `x = y` evaluates to `y` (a `double`) and `y` is zero, the result is `false` because that's what the C standard says should happen. From 6.3.1.2:

> When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the
>   value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

So running this code should **not** print the "equals" message, as indeed [it does for me](http://ideone.com/8dArrc).

Comment: Nitpick: the standard does say that in 6.3.1.2, but that's not why the then-branch is ignored, since there is no conversion to `_Bool` in the OP's program. The reason the then-branch is not taken is 6.8.4.1:2 “the ﬁrst substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0”. The only constraint in 6.8.4.1:1 is “The controlling expression of an if statement shall have scalar type.”

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong operator: `=` is an assignment, `==` is the real comparison (equal). The compiler detects this and warns you just in case this might not be intended (it's far more likely you meant to do a comparison rather than an assignment). This is perfectly valid C (as such it's just a warning, no error). Just to be sure it's intentional, it asks you to add brackets around: `if ((x=y))`. This won't cause any difference code wise, but it shows that the return value is used on its own and the assignment is just part of it (hard to describe).

Edit:
Both lines are printed due to the assignment:

- `x!=y` evaluates to true - as such the first line is printed.
- `x=y` is an assignment, which is essentially saying that `x` should take the value of `y`, which is `0` in this case.

As such the second line shouldn't be written (as `0` evaluates to false), but in general, I'd say it's either a bug or some precision error (this shouldn't happen with a simple assignment of `0`, but you never know).

Comment: This doesn't explain why `x=y` is supposedly printed.

Comment: Mario, you missed the real question. Plus, it's not reproducible, at least, not on my OSX system, so at least for me it's simply unanswerable.

Comment: Updated my answer. This is most likely either some bug or precision issue (although it really shouldn't happen in that case as you're not even doing any calculations).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (x!=y)           // This tests if x is not the same value as y
{
  printf("x!=y\n"); // if x is not the same value as y print this
}

if (x=y)            // This assigns x the value of y, the tests the new value of x
{
  printf("x=y\n");  // if y was not 0, then print this
}
```

I think you wanted:

```
if (x == y) // if x is the same value as y
```

for your second check

**EDIT**
After reading your comments I see that you're getting both prints... I'm not sure what compiler you're using, but I can't reproduce your results. Are you sure the code is correctly copied? When I run I only get `x!=y` as expected as per my explanation.

Run your code with gcc and you'll see it correctly... all I can think of is you're running with some weird non C standard compiler and it's checking the value of x before assigning the y.

Answer (score 0):

The equality operation is `==` and `=` is assignment operator

The correct form is `if(x == y)` but it will run also it `if(x=y)`

because in this case, if will first evaluate  `x=y`,and it will assign a value from `y` to `x` and after it, the expression will treat as  `if(x)` and it will evaluate then.

and now here if `x` has `0`, then `if(x)` will treat as false otherwise true.

So, `x=y` will not get print as output.

Comment: because when you do x=y, it assigns value of y to x which is zero.

Comment: @wantToLearn But the value of `y` being zero means that `"x=y"` should **not** be printed (and it isn't for anybody else, apparently).

Answer (score 0):

It is an suggestion that perhaps you are making an typo.

Usually, you will have:

```
if(condition)
```

In your case the condition is an assignment and hence if always evaluates to true hence the suggestion from compiler.

Comment: It *always* evaluates to true?  What about when assigning a zero? This doesn't explain the reported behavior, and since the problem can't be reproduced, it's hard to answer. I suppose you could say *you  must have run a slightly different program than what you posted.*

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Fischer Has answered your question. You are testing to see if x=y. It doesn't, so your first test is true. Then you are assigning y to x, which returns true as it worked and results in outputting the second print statement.

Comment: But `y` is zero, and when *I* run it there is *no* `x=y` output. The problem is irreproducible and therefore unanswerable.

Comment: It sounds as if it may be down to a compiler quirk. Which compiler did you try with?

Comment: Assigning `y` to `x` does not return true. It returns the value of `y`, which is 0 in this case.